# Cambiar tamaño de una imagen al insertarla a un archivo PDF ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, pdf

Desconozco un poco la manera de trabajar con **PDF** desde **MVC**. Lo que contenga el archivo **.cshtml**, es lo que sera el archivo **PDF**,  le inserte una imagen y me la muestra pero cuando quiero cambiar el tamaño para ajustarla no me lo permite, alguien sabe como podria hacerlo, he intentado con **ccs**, **width** y **height** y nada su tamaño es el mismo.

Me gustaria posicionarlo en la parte de arriba izquierda y reducir su tamaño pero no he podido

[image]

Anexo Codigo de la Vista **.cshtml**

```
@using TPConvenios.App_Data;
    
@model Orden
    @{  
    
    string pathimage = Server.MapPath("~/Content/imagenes/logo_LC.png");
  
 }
<table border="0">
    <tr align="left">
        <td>
            <strong>PRUEBA IMAGEN</strong>
            
            <img src="@pathimage" style="width:10px; height:10px;" />
            
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Como puedo cambiar el tamaño de la imagen??

Comment: Puedes intentar creando una hoja de estilo para impresion, revisa este articulo tal vez te sea de ayuda [Css para impresion](http://desarrolloweb.dlsi.ua.es/libros/html-css/como-crear-una-hoja-de-estilo-para-impresion)

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario pero no me ha funcionado

Comment: Bueno mira esque esta simple, puedes tener dos imagenes, una del tamaño que necesitas para la impresion y crea una clase que tenga la imagen de fondo y asignales esa clase a un div, en tu css de impresion pon la imagen chica y en lo demas deja la imagen normal... y ya, o si solo necesitas que la imagen sea de un solo tamaño pues solo edita la imagen y hazla mas chica

Comment: Tuve que realizar lo ultimo que mencionas, porque como creo una varianble string para obtener esa imagen, creo que por eso no respetara el estilo  ccs. De igual manera Muchas Gracias

Comment: El nombre de la imagen lo tienes alli fijo:  string pathimage = Server.MapPath("~/Content/imagenes/logo_LC.png");, para que es la variable? usaras la imagen en mas partes de tu codigo?

...

aun mas simple puedes poner la imagen logo_LC_100x100.png <-- algo asi y crear esa nueva imagen en tu proyecto con el tamaño exacto que necesitas para la impresion, no tienes que tener una sola imagen para todo tu sistema, puedes crear varias para diferentes paginas y cosas

Comment: No, solo usare la imagen en ese PDF, solo redimensione la imagen. Lo hice así con string pathimage = Server.MapPath("~/Content/imagenes/logo_LC.png"); porque fue la única manera que encontré de agregarle una imagen a mi PDF. Ya que si hacia esto img src="~/Content/imagenes/logo_LC.png" daba este error "the document has no pages."

Comment: ya veo, si este es el caso pues solo abre la imagen en paint .net y cambiale el tamaño, o puedes utilziar cualquier editor de imagen que mas te guste, o hasta hay paginas online que hacen eso:
https://resizeimage.net/

Comment: Gracias utilice esta https://www.iloveimg.com/es/redimensionar-imagen/jpg-cambiar-tamano

Comment: Excelente que bien que lo resolviste, saludos